# Does setting a passed in array in JS to null at the end of the function have any benefit?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, memory-management, pass-by-reference

I recently came across a bit of code at work that has me stumped what the original coder was thinking. The gist of the code was this:

```
function func1(array1) {
   var returnVal = false;

   try
   {
      // Do something. (No effect on array1)
   }

   catch (e)
   {
      CallDebugger(e.description);
   }

   finally 
   {
      // Clean up the memory?
      array1 = null;
   }

   return returnVal;
}

function func2() {
   var arr = [1,2,3]
   var ret = func1(arr)
}
```

My question is: what exactly does setting array1 to null at the end of func1 do? Does it change arr to null in func2? Or does changing array1 to null create a new reference to a null variable? Something else?

Does this have any potential benefits as far as memory leak is concerned?

Comment: `array1` is just a local variable (its value is a copy of the reference to `arr` in `func2`), and setting it to `null` doesn't have an affect to the variable in `func2`. Local variables are garbage collected after the function has been executed, hence it looks superfluous to nullify a local variable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems quite unreasonable to do `array1 = null` in that case.

> What exactly does setting array1 to null at the end of func1 do? Does it change arr to null in func2?

Basically, `array1` is a copy of reference to `arr` in `func2`. So that assignment will change variable only in `func1` scope and nowhere else, so `arr` in `func2` stays unchanged. And doing so in finally statement at the end of a function, is not useful, because `func1` ends right after finnaly statement and reference to `array1` will be garbage collected and no one will ever know that it was set to `null`(expect if it was in a closure before finally, but you say it's not).

> Or does changing array1 to null create a new reference to a null variable?

It just sets `array1`'s value to null, and as I said before: `arr` in `func2` won't be changed in that case.

:)